# Vimscript: How to use a parameter with a function that uses read?

Tags: vim

I just started learning Vimscript.

I want to write a function that opens the output of a bash function in a split.

If I do something like `:call OutputScript("echo 'hello'")`, I want a new buffer to open that has "hello" in it.

I tried the following code:

```
function! OutputScript(cmd)                                                      
   if winbufnr(2) == -1                                                       
     silent vsplit output                                                     
   else                                                                       
     silent wincmd l                                                          
   endif                                                                      
   silent normal ggdG                                                         
   read! a:cmd
endfunction
```

If I `:call OutputScript("echo 'hello'")`, my output window looks like this:

```
bash: a:cmd: command not found
```

What syntax do I need to use `cmd` as a parameter for `read`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juste replace `read! a:cmd` by:

```
exe "read! ".a:cmd
```

The `read` command, as most of vim commands, don't expect vim variables. In order to use variables with common commands, you have to "encapsulate" it into an `exe` command, which can understand any vim expression.

The `.` is the vim operator for concatenating two strings.

Comment: Yes, each shortcut which can't start any other command can be used; so `exe`, `exec`, `execu`... can be used, but not `ex`, because there are the `exit` and `exusage` commands

Comment: When you will be a bit more familiar with vim (or even before that), you really should try the Quickrun plugin, which helps you in many ways with getting output from external language: http://vimawesome.com/plugin/quickrun-vim

Comment: thanks that is eally useful and kind of what i wanted. I am using vim for a while, but only now i started to invest time in vimscript and plugins to improve my efficieny.